# Adding additional option tag on a SELECT whose data is being filled from backend --not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I am working on a jquery/javascript project where a select field called COUNTRY is being populated from backend. The code and  api request is coming from backend and has no such code in frontend to manipulate.

I need to append an option tag "Please select" in the beginning and select it but its not happening because of asynchronous nature of select list filling from backend and since i have no access of when that data is going to fill the list and as well as I cannot make API request from frontend.

I just need to append an option tag in the beginning when that data comes from backend.

I am using below code for appending::

```
$('#order_shipping_address_municipality').prepend('<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>');
```

order_shipping_address_municipality is the id of select tag, whose options lists populated from servers response.

In normal scenario this code should work but because of asynchronous nature this field is getting prepended then its value is overriden by servers response that is the list coming from server.

Any suggestion is apreciated how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Exactly *how* is your `select` being filled via ajax?  Did you write the code that populates it?  If not, who did?  Is it a 3rd-party plugin?   Which one?   If it's a proper plugin, there will be a way to hook into it.   If it's something you wrote, you can add a way to hook in.   There are (at least) 2 alternatives, but they're going to *extremely* hacky - better to hook in correctly.

Comment: the code is written in backend in ruby templating language and relevand ajax is also written there. I am getting a template which is prepopullated with select values from ajax when page loads. I hope it clears your doubt.